# How can I extract a single GOP as images from a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I need to extract a complete GOP (group of pictures) from an MPEG-4 video and turn every frame in that GOP into a full BMP image.

For example, I imagine something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mp4 -gop 2 d:\%02d.bmp
```

Does this exist in ffmpeg? If not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no such command. You will have to use `ffprobe` and some scripting.

Comment: @slhck then as an alternative, may I extract all the frames normally but with the name that reference its type and GOP number and frame order in the name itself (as you kindly suggested), such as that, Frame001_GOP001_Pframe.bmp. and thanks for everything.

Comment: There's also no built-in command for that. If you are experienced with scripting languages you could however easily accomplish it. I have no time to come up with a full solution though.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for everything GOD may bless you.